# x86 Entering Graphics Mode on Macs

Tags: macos, assembly, graphics, x86, dos

I am try to enter graphics mode in assembly on my Mac for learning purposes mostly. I have seen how to do it on Windows based like...

```
mov ax, 13h
int 10h
```

However, since I am on a Mac, I cannot use 'int' calls. Instead I use 'syscall.' So next I looked through Apples system calls [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1504.3.12/bsd/kern/syscalls.master) in hopes of finding something but I didn't come across anything that seemed helpful. Lastly I tried what how I would think the Mac equivalent would be like but I was confused without system calls. So....

```
mov rax, 0x200000(number) ; The number would be the system call
syscall                   ; int equivalent
```

I don't know what the number there would be. This may not even be possible, and if that is the case please say so, otherwise if anyone has any ideas if I'm headed in the right direction or completely wrong direction, help is appreciated.

Comment: mov ax,13h int 10h works on windows only in a dos emulation. A well known portable dos emulation is Dosbox, try to see if it runs on Mac, because otherwise this is a dead end. Modern systems don't easily allow raw access to hardware or other preboot resources.

Comment: If you wish, you can use OpenGL API in assembly language. Or you can use some widget toolkit, such as Qt or GTK+. Or you can write DOS code and use DOSBox, as suggested by Marco van de Voort above. Or you can write real-mode code in a custom bootloader and OS won't be limiting you. It depends on what do you want to accomplish and how.